# How to know when to use `a`, `an` or `the` in ScalaTest Matchers when asserting exceptions?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am reading the section on [Testing Exceptions](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.8/org/scalatest/Matchers.html#checkingForExpectedExceptions) on ScalaTest documentation and looking at examples such as

```
an [IndexOutOfBoundsException] should be thrownBy s.charAt(-1)
```

I tested `a` and that works too

```
a [IndexOutOfBoundsException] should be thrownBy s.charAt(-1)
```

and

```
val thrown = the [IndexOutOfBoundsException] thrownBy s.charAt(-1)
```

I am confused and there is little to no documentation about these keywords.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, [scalatest docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#expectedExceptions) aren't that detailed about that, but it's more or less like this:

You should use `a` when you just want to assert on the type of exception thrown, but not it's contents (e.g. message, nested exception, etc.), but the implementation and behavior are otherwise identical

You should use `an` when exception class starts with a vowel - just because of English spelling rules. Behind the scenes, they are represented by different machinery ([AMatcher](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.8/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/matchers/AMatcher.scala) vs. [AnMatcher](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.8/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/matchers/AnMatcher.scala)), but behavior is virtually identical (the only difference I ever observed is the use of "a" vs. "an" in the failure message)

You should use `the` when you want to assert on the type of exception thrown, and also capture the exception instance to perform additional assertions (on the message, nested exception, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the library source code `a` and `an` are exactly the same:

```
  /**
   * This method enables the following syntax: 
   *
   * <pre class="stHighlight">
   * a [RuntimeException] should be thrownBy { ... }
   * ^
   * </pre>
   */
  def a[T: ClassTag]: ResultOfATypeInvocation[T] =
    new ResultOfATypeInvocation(classTag)

  /**
   * This method enables the following syntax: 
   *
   * <pre class="stHighlight">
   * an [Exception] should be thrownBy { ... }
   * ^
   * </pre>
   */
  def an[T : ClassTag]: ResultOfAnTypeInvocation[T] =
    new ResultOfAnTypeInvocation(classTag)

  /**
   * This method enables the following syntax: 
   *
   * <pre class="stHighlight">
   * the [FileNotFoundException] should be thrownBy { ... }
   * ^
   * </pre>
   */
  def the[T : ClassTag](implicit pos: source.Position): ResultOfTheTypeInvocation[T] =
    new ResultOfTheTypeInvocation(classTag, pos)
```

However, `the` lets you examine the exception further if you need to with methods like `getMessage`. Example from the doc you referenced:

```
the [ArithmeticException] thrownBy 1 / 0 should have message "/ by zero"
```

If you only care about correct exception type use `a`/`an`. If you need to check exception type as well as its message use `the`.

Each test failure generated would have slightly different text due to string representation of these matchers (if you care about grammar in your code):

```
// from ResultOfATypeInvocation:
override def toString: String = "a [" + clazz.getName + "]"
```

vs

```
// from ResultOfAnTypeInvocation:
override def toString: String = "an [" + clazz.getName + "]"
```

for instance.